# SQL query for displaying teacher attendance

Tags: mysql

My teacher table is like:'

[image]

I have a teacher attendance table with data like as shown below:-
[image]

I'm trying to write codes which when executed will populate an excel file in the format given below. Where A= Absent, P= Present and, S= Sunday.

[image]

Logic for Present (P) : For any given date if ta_clock_in_tm & ta_clock_out_tm both are present then it's P.

Logic for Absent (A) : If no records exist for dates of the month in the teacher attendance table then it's A.

I also want to mark Sundays as S and calculate Total Present days and absent days.

I have not done anything like this before. I'm really confused about the sql query. Are both my tables enough to meet my requirement??

```
function export_to_mwiseallattenexcel($mnth)
{
    $columnHeader ='';
    $setData='';
    $currYr = date("Y");
    $noDaysInGvnMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mnth, $currYr);
    $columnHeader = "Sl No"."\t"."Emp Name"."\t";
    for($i=1; $i<=$noDaysInGvnMonth; $i++)
    {
        $columnHeader .= $i."\t";
    }
    $columnHeader .= "Total Working Days"."\t"."Total Absent"."\t"."Total Present"."\t"."Remarks"."\t";
    $sql="";//<---WHAT TO WRITE HERE?????
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $rowData = '';
            foreach($row as $value)
            {
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                $rowData .= $value;
            }
            $setData .= trim($rowData)."\n";
        }
    }

    header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Attendance_as.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";        
}
```

Please help me with the SQL query. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I have tried so far is shown up there. I just need a little guide as to how to query the tables to get data in the given format.

Comment: The question is about what goes in `$sql`, all the rest is irrelevant. So you haven't shown any attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Open a connection to your server. There you can query EVERY command you want:
The code is:

```php
        try {
            $sql = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost:3306; dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pwd');
            $sql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $statement = "do something";
            $sql -> query($statement)
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: (f) ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Some interesting commands are:

```
CREATE TABLE table (any datatypes); -> creates new table
INSERT INTO table () VALUES (value1),(value2); -> fills table with values
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE old_name new_bane datatype; -> change table
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN user_id; -> drops a column from a database
DELETE FROM table WHERE condition; -> delete all values where condition is true
UPDATE table SET data=value WHERE condition; updates values inside a table where condition is true
```